# Evaluating Integral using delta destribituiom

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I have to evaluate an integral $\int_{- \infty }^{\infty} \frac{dt}{t^2} \delta (\cos t)$

The notion i have used that, we only get $\delta (\cos t) $ when t is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2} $.  Therefore the answer should be $\frac{4}{\pi^2}$.

Is it the right way I'm thinking?

Comment: No, not quite.  Note that the Dirac Delta is "active" for any value $x$ for which $\cos(x)=0$.  Moreover, one needs to appropriately define the distribution appropriately.  In this case, one can proceed formally, operating as if the Dirac Delta is a function (it isn't) and "change" variables, letting $u=\cos(t)$.

Comment: As mentioned previous commenter, there is set of points which satisfy $\cos(x)=0$, so what you'd like to do here is to replace integration with summation over this set

Comment: Don't forget the need to divide by the derivative of $\cos$ at the zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\delta\pars{\cos\pars{t}} \over t^{2}}
\,\dd t} & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\,\,\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}
{\delta\pars{t - \bracks{n + 1/2}\pi} \over \verts{-\sin\pars{t}}}
{\dd t \over t^{2}} =
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}{1 \over \bracks{\pars{n + 1/2}\pi}^{\,2}}
\\[5mm] & =
{4 \over \pi^{2}}\bracks{2\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n + 1}^{2}}} =
{8 \over \pi^{2}}\bracks{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}} -
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{8 \over \pi^{2}}\bracks{{3 \over 4}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}} =
{8 \over \pi^{2}}\,{3 \over 4}\,{\pi^{2} \over 6} = \color{#f00}{1}
\end{align}

Comment: Are we considering the sum because there are lot of possible ways that satisfy the delta distribution? If we had only one consideration, my thought was correct ?

Comment: @SabbirHasan $\cos\left(t\right) = 0$ has infinite solutions $\left\{t_{n} = \left(n + 1/2\right)\pi\,,\quad n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ and the integration interval is $\left(-\infty,+\infty\right)$. So, $\underline{all}$ the roots 'yield a contribution'. One case of 'just $\underline{one}$ root' inside the interval is, $\underline{for\ example}$
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}{\delta\left(\cos\left(t\right)\right) \over t^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}t = {4 \over \pi^{2}}
$$

Comment: I understand everything you have done except the  this conversion ${\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over ({2n + 1})^{2}}} $=${\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over ({n })^{2}}} -{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over ({2n })^{2}}}  $  Didi you use telescopic method? 

Could you please explain this?

Comment: @SabbirHasan $2n$ and $\left(2n + 1\right)$ are $\underline{even}$ and $\underline{odd}$ numbers, respectively. You can split a series in two series:1)Sum over $\underline{odd}$ and 2) sum over $\underline{even}$ as follows
$$
\sum_{n}\mathrm{f}\left(n\right) =
\sum_{n}\mathrm{f}\left(2n + 1\right) + \sum_{n}\mathrm{f}\left(2n\right)
$$

Comment: I thought you had used $TELESCOPIC$ method to  do that step.  It seems the you did the sum using Fourier  technique. I'm I wrong?  Could you please give me a link so I can understand how to do this kind of sum. 

Thanks a lot for your help. :)